# Is there any way to skip the root folder from where the search starts for preVisitDirectory when using Files.walkFileTree?

Tags: java

Im using Files.walkFileTree and I'm also getting a call to preVisitDirectory for the root folder from where the search starts. Any way to skip this?

For example: Files.walkFileTree for /test/ will first call preVisitDirectory with /test/ and then the test of the subfolders of /test/.

Any way to make it start directly with the subfolders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Files.walkFileTree(root, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override 
    public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory( final Path dir, final BasicFileAttributes attrs ) throws IOException {
        if ( dir.equals( root ) ) return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            process( dir );
            return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE; //or CONTINUE for recursive processing
        }
    } 
);
```